# AngularJS AutoComplete Not Working In IE8

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have the following code for autoComplete

```
<div id="ng-app" ng-app ng-controller="AutoCtrls">
    <input list="names" ng-model="selected">
    <datalist id="names">
        <option value="{{name}}" ng-repeat="name in names"></option>
    </datalist>
     selected = {{selected}}
</div>
```

and in app.js

```
function AutoCtrls($scope, Restangular) {
    $scope.names = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar",
   "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean",
   "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", 
   "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];
   alert('ok 1');
}
```

The problem I am facing is this doesn't work in IE8, however this does work in Chrome and Firefox.

What could be the reason and how can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 and 9 don't support `<datalist>`: http://caniuse.com/datalist

Comment: Jeff What other alternates for `<datalist>`?

Comment: There's [Angular-UI's typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead), and probably a few other things too.